# Can this Fourier transformed function be transformed into partial fraction?

Tags: fourier-transform, partial-fractions

Hi I'm self learning stochastic process, I've come across a problem and found 
$$H=\frac{2+j(2w)}{(1-w^2)+j(2w)} \\
|H(iw)|^2=\frac{2^2+(2w)^2}{(1-w^2)^2+(2w)^2} \\$$
In attempt to find the power spectral density with partial fraction,
$$S_y(w)=|H(iw)|^2 S_x(w)=\frac{2^2+(2w)^2}{(1-w^2)^2+(2w)^2} \frac{3}{2^2+w^2} \\
= \frac{12(1+w^2)}{(w^2+1)^2(w^2+4)}
= \frac{A}{(w^2+1)^2}+\frac{B}{(w^2+4)} \\
A = \frac{12(1+w^2)}{w^2+4} = 0, w=\pm\sqrt{-1}= \pm j \\
B=\frac{12(1+w^2)}{(w^2+1)^2} = \frac{12(1-4)}{(-4+1)^2}=\frac{-36}{9}=-4, w^2+4=0, w=\pm2j$$
Is complex $w$ even making any sense? Because I thought w is part of $iw$, then it should be real if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{12(1+w^2)}{(w^2+1)^2(w^2+4)}=\frac{12}{(w^2+1)(w^2+4)}=\frac{4}{w^2+1}-\frac{4}{w^2+4}$$

Comment: that's right. can w be imaginary? That's what I wanted to ask.

Comment: Now, I think of it, $\omega$ can be negative.